# Matching complex path to simplified version of it

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to figure if it is possible to write a regex expression that matches a path ignoring some parts of this path, lets see some example

**full path >> simple path**

```
SomeNameA.{key.val}/SomeNameAB.{key.val} >> SomeNameA/SomeNameAB

SomeNameY.{key.val}{key2.val2}/XYZ/SomeOtherPath.{key.val} >> SomeNameY/XYZ/SomeOtherPath
```

basically I want to discard everything after the first "." (dot) until the "/".
Right now I manually doing the split in the "/" then, finding the position of "." and doing a substring of it, manually matching it.

So later when I receive the object with the full path, I can check if we have something configure for it with the simple path

for simplicity, lets say I'm trying something similar to this:

```
String fullPath = "SomeNameY.{key.val}{key2.val2}/XYZ/SomeOtherPath.{key.val}";
String simplePath = "SomeNameY/XYZ/SomeOtherPath";
if (!fullPath.match(simplePath)) return;
```

In this example I'm expecting it to return true so I can continue with the setup of that particular item.

For this case scenario I'm looking for an exact match, case sensitive and nothing else between or after it.

So this "**A.{key.val}/B**" should only match "**A/B**" and not match this "**A/b**" or this "**A/z/B**".

Sure this full path "**A.{key.val}/B**" and "**A.{key.val}/B.{key.val}**" will have the same simple version but this won't happen by design, so no concern about it.

Comment: `String simplifiedFullPath  = fullPath.replaceAll("\\.?\\{.*?\\}","");`

Comment: Hi there, thanks! That replace does work fine! I'll use it and post an answer with it later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following **@Pshemo** comment, using the regex to replace the unwanted parts of the path works, so instead of try to make them match with the regex, it just remove the extra characters and do a normal comparison over the result

```
String simplePath = "SomeNameY/XYZ/SomeOtherPath";
String fullPath = "SomeNameY.{key.val}{key2.val2}/XYZ/SomeOtherPath.{key.val}";
String simplifiedPath = fullPath.replaceAll("\\.?\\{.*?\\}","");
if (!simplePath.equals(simplifiedPath)) return;
```